# 2-D Array of structures -> unable to fix a segmentation fault :(

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

SO (pun intended) I want to solve this question from HackerEarth: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/multi-dimensional/practice-problems/algorithm/the-wealthy-landlord/

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ll long long 

int main () {
    ll int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    ll int i, j, a, b;
    ll int TOTAL;

    typedef struct {
        ll int flag;
        ll int count;
        // int fc[N]; // farmer cost OR cost for farmer i
        ll int *fc;
    } land;

    // check whether all of them have been
    // initialised to 0
    // printf("%d ", arr[2][2].count);
    // yes

    land arr[1000][1000];
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<1000; j++) {
            arr[i][j].fc = (ll int *)calloc(N, sizeof(ll int));
        }
    }

    ll int x1, y1, x2, y2, c;
    ll int ta, tb; // temp a // temp b
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &c);
        // the array index starts from 0
        // so to match the inputs to the correct indices
        // the inputs must be reduced by one
        for(a=x1; a<=x2; a++) {
            for (b=y1; b<=y2; b++) {
                ta = a-1;
                tb = b-1;

                arr[ta][tb].count++;
                if(arr[ta][tb].count >= 2)
                    arr[ta][tb].flag = 1;

                arr[ta][tb].fc[i] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    ll int k;
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<1000; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j].flag == 1) {
                for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                    TOTAL += arr[i][j].fc[k];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%lld", TOTAL);
    return 0;
}
```

RESULT: Runtime Error (SIGSEGV)

Compilation Log:
Compiled Successfully

> Execution Log: Execution failed.
> Segmentation Fault : This occurs
>   because of an out-of-scope array index that is causing a buffer
>   overflow, an incorrectly initialized pointer, etc. A signal is
>   generated when a program either tries to read or write outside the
>   memory that is allocated for it or to write memory that can only be
>   read. For example, you are accessing a[-1] in a language that does not
>   support negative indices for an array.

I've edited this code multiple times and fixed various issues by looking at various SO questions. Now it is so close to working, but it just makes a straight face and says segmentation fault. The worst kind of fault that gives you little to no hints on how it should be fixed. I am out of ideas!

ALSO - There probably is a better method to solve this problem which does not involve arrays inside a 2-D array of structures, but I would love to learn how to fix this segmentation fault.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the segfault?

Comment: The line `land arr[1000][1000];` looks a bit suspect, to me. You are asking to create an automatic  variable of size >= 24 million bytes - on the stack!! If that don't cause Stack Overflow, I'm not sure what will. (You *could* try moving out of `main` and making it `static` - not the best code, I agree, but it may help diagnosis.)

Comment: When compiled with MSVC (VS2019) I get this warning (along with quite a few others): **warning C6262: Function uses '24000112' bytes of stack:  exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to heap.**

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you so much for your feedback! At least now I know which lines are causing problems. In college, we have barely started data structures (finished only arrays). This means that I know nothing about stacks and heaps hehe, and I should probably try a simpler method to solve the problem. Just out of curiosity though, I would love to see what this code would like after it has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line: `land arr[1000][1000];` declares `arr` as an **automatic** variable, which means that space is allocated to it from the *stack*. Put simply, this *stack* is memory assigned for local use when a function is called (and `main` is really just a function called by the operating system when you run the program).

Typically, the amount of space available on the stack is limited - typically 16 - 64 kilobytes. However, your `arr` variable (assuming 8 bytes for a `long long int` and 8 bytes for a pointer) will require **more than 24 megabytes**. This is almost certainly what is causing your "Stack Overflow!"

A 'quick fix' to this problem is to declare the variable `static`. This means that space is allocated at compile time (or, more likely, at link time) and is 'locked' into memory while the program is running. (You may notice that the size of your executable file increases by 24 MB after you do this - depending on your platform!)

Here is a slightly modified version of your code, with this correction, along with a couple of other suggested improvements (all marked with the "///" comment delimiter:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ll long long 

int main() {
    ll int N;
    scanf("%lld", &N); /// The plain "%d" format expects an "int" argument - use "%lld" for "long long int"
    ll int i, j, a, b;
    ll int TOTAL = 0;  /// If you don't INITIALIZE "TOTAL" it could start off with ANY value whatsoever!

    typedef struct {
        ll int flag;
        ll int count;
        // int fc[N]; // farmer cost OR cost for farmer i
        ll int* fc;
    } land;

    // check whether all of them have been
    // initialised to 0
    // printf("%d ", arr[2][2].count);
    // yes

    static land arr[1000][1000]; /// Without "static" this array (~ 24 Megabytes) will overflow the stack!
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            arr[i][j].fc = (ll int*)calloc(N, sizeof(ll int));
        }
    }

    ll int x1, y1, x2, y2, c;
    ll int ta, tb; // temp a // temp b
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &c);
        // the array index starts from 0
        // so to match the inputs to the correct indices
        // the inputs must be reduced by one
        for (a = x1; a <= x2; a++) {
            for (b = y1; b <= y2; b++) {
                ta = a - 1;
                tb = b - 1;

                arr[ta][tb].count++;
                if (arr[ta][tb].count >= 2)
                    arr[ta][tb].flag = 1;

                arr[ta][tb].fc[i] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    ll int k;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j].flag == 1) {
                for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    TOTAL += arr[i][j].fc[k];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%lld", TOTAL);
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.